# Перевести число в дату JS

Tags: javascript

Как допустим число 1610628620  перевести в дату? И можно ли с помощю библиотеки moment?

Comment: Да почему с помощью библиотеки-то? Стандартные методы для работы с датой присутствуют в языке

Answer (score 5):

```js
const date = new Date(1610628620 * 1000);
console.log(date)

const m = moment(1610628620 * 1000);
console.log(m.toDate())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Такими темпами скоро Hello World будем через библиотеки писать

Comment: А почему на `1000` умножаем?

Comment: @НебытьрабомнаРуси, автор вопроса не указал, что у него за магическое число, но оно похоже на [Unix-время](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F) — количество секунд, прошедшее с 1 января 1970 года. Объекты `Date` в JavaScript тоже отсчитывают время с 1 января 1970 года, но в миллисекундах, отсюда и умножение на `1000`. Конструктор `Date` принимает время в разных форматах, если это единственное целое число, то оно интерпретируется как кол-во миллисекунд, прошедших с 1 января 1970 года.

Comment: @wololo Спасибо